# Logic Pro X images replaced by words fix?

Tags: software, logic

so i accidentally pressed some buttons at logic and long story short some images and widgets like the red circle rec button or the drum kit at the new project are now replaced just by words (eg REC and drummer)

I include some screenshots so that you can fully understand the problem. The top ones are taken from garageband. That was the way everything was presented at logic before shit happened.
The goal is to reverse this thing and go back to the current garageband way.
I tried to find the solution but failed and i guess its something very silly and easy to fix so...yeah.

[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you switch Logic Pro to use the *Advanced Tools* settings.

To change this back, go to *Logic Pro > Preferences > Advanced Tools...* and uncheck the "Show Advanced Tools" checkbox. Once you have done that, Logic will be back again to the simplified Garageband layout, including the items you have shown in your screenshot on the top.

[image: Logic Pro Preferences]

The downside is that you lose access to the advanced features in Logic Pro when do this.